# How to set precision and scale in ALTER TABLE

Tags: postgresql, types, precision, ddl, arbitrary-precision

I have working code with PostgreSQL 9.3:

```
ALTER TABLE meter_data ALTER COLUMN w3pht TYPE float USING (w3pht::float);
```

but don't know how to set **precision** and **scale**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type `float` does not have precision and scale. Use [**`numeric(precision, scale)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) instead if you need that.

[Per documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT)

> The data types `real` and `double precision` are inexact, variable-precision numeric types.

For your given example:

```
ALTER TABLE meter_data ALTER COLUMN w3pht TYPE numeric(15,2)
USING w3pht::numeric(15,2)  -- may or may not be required
```

The manual:

> A `USING` clause must be provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new type.

Example: if the old data type is `text`, you need the `USING` clause. If it's `float`, you don't.

Comment: Thanks its work.. ALTER TABLE meter_data ALTER COLUMN w3pht TYPE numeric USING (w3pht::numeric(15, 2));

Comment: No that code specifically does not work. The column type is set to unlimited precision, but all the existing values were rounded to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

As per [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-numeric.html), you **can** select the minimum number for the floating point numbers using syntax `float(n)` where `n` is the minimum number of **binary** digits, up to 53.

However, to store decimal values at all, use `numeric(precision, scale)` or its synonym `decimal(precision, scale)` but notice that these are hard limits; according to the documentation:

> If the scale of a value to be stored is greater than the declared
>   scale of the column, the system will round the value to the specified
>   number of fractional digits. Then, if the number of digits to the left
>   of the decimal point exceeds the declared precision minus the declared
>   scale, an error is raised.

Thus your alter table could be:

```
ALTER TABLE meter_data
    ALTER COLUMN w3pht TYPE numeric(10, 2)
    USING (w3pht::numeric(10, 2));
```

for 2 digits right of decimal point and 10 total digits. However if you do not 
need to specify limits, simple `numeric` will allow *"up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after"*.